# Need help with the negation of a statement.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The statement is

> For each $\epsilon$ there is a corresponding $\delta$ such that for any set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ if $\mu(A) < \delta$ then $\nu(A) < \epsilon$.

My thought on the negation is there exists an $\epsilon$ such that for all $\delta$ there is a set $A$ such that if $\mu(A)<\delta$, then $\nu(A) > \epsilon$.

Comment: Correct. Can you also mathematically express "conclusion does not hold" so that we can be sure about that also?

Comment: Okay I updated it.

Comment: Done. I just wanted to make sure you did not write $\mu(a) > \delta$ then $\nu(a) > \epsilon$. You have got it.

Comment: Thanks; this is the most complicated statement I've had to negate in a long time so I'm a little rusty. I had a slightly different negation before which trivialized the proof I'm looking at so I knew it was wrong else they wouldn't have gone through this difficult work.

Comment: @Andrew The "trick" is negating your $p\to q$ statement to $\neg(p\to q)\equiv\neg(\neg p\lor q)\equiv p\land\neg q$. In your case, what are $p$ and $q$?

Comment: You are welcome, @Andrew

Comment: p =  $\mu(A) < \delta$
q =  $\nu(A) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Exactly. Your work *should* be done now. `:-)`

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: You're wrong.

Answer (score 4):

First try to convert your statement into more formal logical symbolism,
$$
(\forall \epsilon)(\exists \delta)(\forall A\in\mathcal{A})(\mu(A)<\delta\to\nu(A)<\epsilon),
$$
which can then be easily negated:
$$
(\exists \epsilon)(\forall \delta)(\exists A\in\mathcal{A})(\mu(A)<\delta\land\nu(A)\geq\epsilon).
$$
Now, can you express the above statement in a more "language-friendly" way?

Comment: For all epsilon there exists delta such that for all $A \in \mathcal{A}, \mu(A) < \delta$ implies $\nu(A)<\epsilon$. The negated statement you said is there exists $\epsilon$ such that for all $\delta$ there exists $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(A)<\delta$ implies $\nu(A) \geq \epsilon$.

Comment: You sure that is what I said? I don't see any "implies" in what I wrote.

Comment: @Andrew: Your attempt was wrong. Daniel's is correct. The implication "A implies B" can be seen as a promise "if you satisfy A I grant you B", and its negation is **breaking of the promise**, which means "you satisfy A but I don't grant you B".